# PHP Mysqli prepared statement with using password() function

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've been working with mysqli prepared statements in PHP and have done many with no problems.  Now I'm working on encrypting some previously plain-text passwords, and I need to use the mysql password() function in my query.

This is my code:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select id from tm_users where login = ? and pwEnc = password(?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
$stmt->execute();
$userdata = $stmt->get_result();
```

This code is generating the error:

> PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in /var/www/...../test.php

If I remove the password function from the query, I don't get an error.  But, of course, I need the function in order for the query to work properly!

Can somebody suggest what I should do to fix this?

Comment: You should not be using `password()` for user passwords. This is not the purpose of this SQL function. You should be only storing a hash of a password. To generate hash use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Note also that the `PASSWORD()` function was deprecated somewhere in MySQL 5.7, and has been removed entirely in MySQL 8.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  When doing it using php password_hash, is there any way to verify the password within the mysql query itself?  Or do I need to select the stored hash and then verify it in php?